# How to format clipboard text as data row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, formatting, copy-paste

I've noticed copying text with a link preserves the link when pasted in Google Sheets. I've also tried copying an inline list from an HTML page and noticed it gets copied as two rows.

Is it possible to format text such that it gets pasted as a single row and two columns in Google Sheets? If so, how?

(I have control of the text being copied and I can use a bit of GApps JS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are looking for **direct transposed paste** which is supported in Google Sheets via keyboard shortcut combo:

- <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`E`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`S`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`E`**</kbd> `(for Windows+Chrome)`
- <kbd>**`CONTROL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`OPTION`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`E`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`S`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`E`**</kbd> `(for OSX)`

Also can be accessed via Special Paste:

[image: 0]

---

You are able to paste CSV data as is into the spreadsheet and go to **Data** selecting **Split text to columns...** and even further specifying the delimiter:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

Also, you can simply use keyboard shortcut combo:

- **<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`D`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`E`</kbd>** `(for Windows+Chrome)`
- **<kbd>`CONTROL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`OPTION`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`D`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`E`</kbd>** `(for OSX)`

Comment: Thanks(+1) that looks pretty close. I didn't quite understand how to use the keyboard shortcut. I did find another function that does what I need: Split text to columns (in the paste context menu). Is there a shortcut for that ?

Comment: try: LEFT ALT + D + E

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza answer updated

Comment: using `LEFT ALT+D+E` types `∂´`. This is on OSX. Sorry, but I feel I'm missing something simple with the shortcut notion. Is it hold `LEFT ALT` then type `D`, then `E` (with left alt pressed), press then release each key ?

Comment: you can do it like LEFT ALT + D + E where you holding alt key entire time. or you can do it LEFT ALT + D  and then pressing E key. both approaches work (on Windows). for OSX its a game changer: the combo is: Ctrl + Option + e + d

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza answer updated

Comment: awesome! thank you so much for taking your time to document both OSX and Windows